# zend framework routing and layout

Tags: zend-framework

I have a CMS base controller that most of my other controllers extend. It has a default action for list, create, read, update and delete actions, all of them set the title based on the name of the resource(s) the user is working with.

The index action defaults to contain only one row:

```
$this->_forward('list');
```

Now my problem is that my previously set title is gone when I open the index of a CMS controller. I'd like to know what could be happening and what is the best solution of this.

Note that the problem does not appear if I rename my list action to index. It may also be relevant that changing the view title in the index action does not work.

Comment: Do i understand you correctly? If the user hits /index you want the title to be "index" and not "list", but still get the list-output?

Comment: Let's say the user is editing articles. I want him to see the title as "List of Articles" when he hits /cms/articles. This does happen when he hits /cms/articles/list

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, where do you set your title and in what way do you do it? Personally my titles are only two parts like "Application: current action". To achieve this i do the following:

```
//layout.phtml
<?=$this->headTitle()->setPrefix('APP: ')?>

//indexAction()
$this->_forward('list');

//listAction()
$this->view->headTitle()->append('List Data');
```

I do this for every action separately and since i do not assign a title within indexAction() i get the full wanted title "APP: List Data" inside listAction(). This remains true if i have my edit action like the following

```
//editAction()
if (!is_numeric($this->_getParam('id'))) {
  return $this->_forward('list');
}
```

If this doesn't do it for you, your scripts will be needed to look for an error elsewhere :)

Comment: Actually I don't use the container, I just set the title as a regular object variable like this: $this->view->title = 'My new title';

Comment: Should work anyways :S Maybe show the relevant parts of your Controller and View scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my initial idea of this issue having to do something with routing was right. I'm loading the layout in a preDispatch action of an action controller. So what actually happend was that I re-created my layout view after setting the title attribute in the index action.